# java extend or wrap a class to add extra functionality

Tags: java, list, collections, pagination, wrapper

When you want to add some extra information into a class, what way would you prefer: would you extend that class or make a wrapper around it?

In my particular scenario, I want to add some pagination information with a `List` that I get from database. That pagination information will include:

```
int currentPage;
int totalResults;
int containedResultsIndex;
int totalcontainedResults;
```

and a couple of methods:

```
Boolean isNextPageAvailable();
Boolean isPrevPageAvailable();
```

Whats your opinion, extend or wrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- in your case wrap the existing `List` and make your class implement `List` itself, delegating all methods the the original list (which is passed in constructor, for example)
- inheritance isn't always wrong, but in this case you won't know what class to extend - will it be `ArrayList`, or `LinkedList` ?

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you're asking whether you should favor inheritance or composition in your situation.  I would say that you are not creating a new implementation of `List` and you don't really care how `List` is implemented, so inheritance doesn't fit your problem.  Instead, you're providing paging functionality.  I would create a class that generically wraps up (encapsulates) the paging logic using `List` or some other generic collection.

Answer (score 3):

Too much extends is evil, and will make your code difficult to read/understand go with composition, just create a new class that has a Collection and your extra members needed for pagination.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to wrap where possible. Especially in your `List` example - the wrapper class can contain any list type, whereas a extended class is tied to a specific concrete superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you extend, you will not be able to call the new methods through the super class reference. It is best to just wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

Having an elegant PagingList (extending List) is an adequate approach.

- Why delegating when you can inherit the stuff you need?
- It's like the relationship between FileReader and BufferedFileReader ( And nobody would say that's bad practice).